# Oracle Sub Select with Inner Join in Laravel Eloquent way

Tags: oracle, laravel, eloquent

I am converting Oracle SQL into Laravel. The problem is how can make the code below in **Eloquent way**. I am more proficient in raw SQL though.

```
SELECT idx, ntiIdx, readCnt
    FROM (SELECT a.idx, a.ntiIdx, a.readCnt
          FROM EH_APPLICANT a 
          INNER JOIN EH_ITEM I ON a.netIdx = i.idx AND a.userIdx = ?
          ORDER BY testDate DESC, testTime DESC
    ) 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Are you aware that Laravel has no native Oracle support?

Comment: I'm not aware because I'm currently using :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle: Does `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` only return the first row? Why does it have to be a nested query?